# In Eclipse UML2 3.1, if stereotype B is a generalization of stereotype A, does B inherit the meta-class extension of A?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, xmi

Until recently I was using an older version of Eclipse UML2 (2.4) where this worked. After updating to Eclipse UML2 3.1, I receive an IllegalArgumentException when attempting to apply a stereotype generalized from another stereotype to an element of the appropriate extended meta-class. Stepping through the eclipse uml source showed that the attribute "base_Class" was missing in the underlying Ecore model for the stereotype.

Java test code:

```
// Init a resource set to load the standard UML profiles
ResourceSet rset = null;
{
  rset = new ResourceSetImpl();

  rset.getPackageRegistry().put("http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML", UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);      

  // Register the UML resource factory
  rset.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);

  // Get one of the standard profiles to build a jar path 
  final URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("profiles/UML2.profile.uml");
  if(url == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not load 'profiles/UML2.profile.uml' from class path");
  }

  // Need the jarfile path so chop off the file specific stuff
  final String path = url.toExternalForm().split("!")[0] + "!/";

  // Build a uri for this path
  final URI baseURI = URI.createURI(path);


  // Build mappings from 'pathmap://UML_PROFILES' (or metamodels or libraries) to the point at the jarfile path
  final Map<URI,URI> uriMap = rset.getURIConverter().getURIMap();
  // pathmap://UML_PROFILES
  uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.LIBRARIES_PATHMAP), baseURI.appendSegment("libraries").appendSegment(""));
  // pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES
  uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.METAMODELS_PATHMAP), baseURI.appendSegment("metamodels").appendSegment(""));
  // pathmap://UML_PROFILES
  uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.PROFILES_PATHMAP), baseURI.appendSegment("profiles").appendSegment(""));
}

// Load the test profile
Profile test = null;
{
  final URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("profiles/test.profile.uml");
  if(url == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not load 'profiles/test.profile.uml' from class path");
  }

  final Resource r = rset.createResource(URI.createURI(url.toExternalForm()));

  r.load(null);

  test = (Profile)EcoreUtil.getObjectByType(r.getContents(), UMLPackage.Literals.PROFILE);
  if(test == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not load 'profiles/test.profile.uml'");
  }
}

Stereotype A = test.getOwnedStereotype("A");
Stereotype B = test.getOwnedStereotype("B");

Model m = UMLFactory.eINSTANCE.createModel();

org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Package pkg = m.createNestedPackage("pkg");

org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Class c1 = pkg.createOwnedClass("c1", false);
org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Class c2 = pkg.createOwnedClass("c2", false);

pkg.applyProfile(test);

c1.applyStereotype(A);
c2.applyStereotype(B); // throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Test profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<uml:Profile xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML" xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493254282_739829_1797" name="test" metamodelReference="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493254285_456691_1798">
  <eAnnotations xmi:id="_RgZgwVl-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA" source="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML">
    <contents xmi:type="ecore:EPackage" xmi:id="_RgZgwll-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA" name="test" nsURI="http:///schemas/test/_RgUBMFl-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA/0" nsPrefix="test">
      <eClassifiers xmi:type="ecore:EClass" xmi:id="_RgZgw1l-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA" name="A">
        <eAnnotations xmi:id="_RgZgxFl-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA" source="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML" references="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493260539_647682_1799"/>
        <eStructuralFeatures xmi:type="ecore:EReference" xmi:id="_RgZgxVl-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA" name="base_Class" ordered="false" lowerBound="1">
          <eType xmi:type="ecore:EClass" href="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/3.0.0/UML#//Class"/>
        </eStructuralFeatures>
      </eClassifiers>
      <eClassifiers xmi:type="ecore:EClass" xmi:id="_RgZgx1l-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA" name="B" eSuperTypes="_RgZgw1l-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA">
        <eAnnotations xmi:id="_RgZgyFl-EeG_l9KiXhjXuA" source="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML" references="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493272173_447751_1805"/>
      </eClassifiers>
    </contents>
  </eAnnotations>
  <packageImport xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493254285_456691_1798">
    <importedPackage xmi:type="uml:Model" href="pathmap://UML_METAMODELS/UML.metamodel.uml#_0"/>
  </packageImport>
  <packageImport xmi:id="_0primitiveTypestest">
    <importedPackage xmi:type="uml:Model" href="pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES/UMLPrimitiveTypes.library.uml#_0"/>
  </packageImport>
  <packageImport xmi:id="_0javaPrimitiveTypestest">
    <importedPackage xmi:type="uml:Model" href="pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES/JavaPrimitiveTypes.library.uml#_0"/>
  </packageImport>
  <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Stereotype" xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493260539_647682_1799" name="A">
    <ownedAttribute xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385577_849191_1812" name="base_Class" visibility="private" association="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385577_76750_1811">
      <type xmi:type="uml:Class" href="pathmap://UML_METAMODELS/UML.metamodel.uml#Class"/>
    </ownedAttribute>
  </packagedElement>
  <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Stereotype" xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493272173_447751_1805" name="B">
    <generalization xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493436355_971859_1821" general="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493260539_647682_1799"/>
  </packagedElement>
  <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Extension" xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385577_76750_1811" name="" memberEnd="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385578_204693_1813 _17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385577_849191_1812" navigableOwnedEnd="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385578_204693_1813">
    <ownedEnd xmi:type="uml:ExtensionEnd" xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385578_204693_1813" name="extension_A" visibility="private" type="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493260539_647682_1799" aggregation="composite" association="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385577_76750_1811">
      <upperValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralUnlimitedNatural" xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385578_803186_1815" name="" value="1"/>
      <lowerValue xmi:type="uml:LiteralInteger" xmi:id="_17_0_1_1_57a01e4_1329493385578_297198_1814" name=""/>
    </ownedEnd>
  </packagedElement>
</uml:Profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a bug. Report it and if maybe god will help you :-)